# Selecting ID of parent's preceding sibling

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm relatively new to XSLT, and finding preceding-sibling:: quite painful.

Using a very simple example XML:

```
<month>
    <day id="1">Day one was a lovely day</day>
    <day id="2">Day two was balls</day>
    <day id="3">Day three was Wednesday</day>
</month>
```

And some basic XSLT (I'd like each day output to a new file: no problem with this):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/month">
       <xsl:for-each select="day">
           <xsl:result-document href="output/day-{@id}/index.html">
               <xsl:call-template name="page" />
           </xsl:result-document>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="page">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>This is <xsl:value-of select="id" /></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Day of new <xsl:value-of select="@id" /></h1>
                <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>

                <!--PROBLEM HERE:: -->
                Previous: <xsl:value-of select="" />

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem I have is with the final bit (where I've written PROBLEM HERE). I'm trying to get the id of the previous day. I don't seem to be able to get the right `select` value. I've tried all the combinations of `ancestor::` and `../preceding-sibling::day[1]` I can find mentioned anywhere. Please help!

Comment: I haven't checked whether there is a previous node in this code, but assumed it would work for Day 2 and Day 3 at least.

Comment: You do not need to match on the month since all you are doing is processing it's children and XSLT's built in template rules will do that automatically. Remove the for-each on day and template match on day instead that is <xsl:template match="day">. Also if I were you I would lift the called template into the day template so that it is clear that's where that code gets executed and you don't have to figure out where it is called from. It might be easy now but it won't be if you have a bigger stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::day[1]/@id"/>
```

Just that the first one will not have any value as no preceding-sibling `day`.

Comment: Thanks... for some reason I was working on the assumption that this <xsl:value-of> was inside the context of the day... rather than operating on that node itself.